# Installer adding files to an already installed package's dir

Tags: nsis

I am a newcomer to NSIS and I plan to distribute a program `A` using NSIS. Now I would like to provide an additional component `A1` (which cannot be distributed as part of `A` itself), which must put its files into the directory of `A`, failing if `A` is not installed at all. I would also like to be able to install a newer version of `A` without having to re-install `A1`.

Is that possible with NSIS? Can you provide an example of such deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **A** you would just use `InstallDirRegKey` and point it to your uninstall registry key so a newer version installs on top of the old one.

For **A1** you should use `InstallDirRegKey` to read **A**'s key and then verify this location with the [`.onVerifyInstdir` callback](http://anders_k.users.sourceforge.net/public/NSIS/2.46/Manual.html#onverifyinstdir), this will prevent the user from clicking next on the directory page if the correct destination has not been chosen...